# .NET Script Scheduler

Tags: asp.net, scheduled-tasks

Hey I have a .NET .aspx page that I would like to run every hour or so whats the best way to do this ?

I assume it will have to open a browser window to do so and if possible that it closes the window after.

EDIT : I have access over all features on the server

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Option 1**: The cleanest solution would be to write a Windows application that does the work (instead of an aspx page) and schedule this application on the server using the Windows Task Scheduler. This has a few advantages over the aspx approach:

- You can use the features of the Windows Task Scheduler (event log entries if the task could not be started, see the time of the last run, run the task in the context of a specific user, etc.).
- You don't need to "simulate" a web browser call.
- Your page cannot be "accidentally" called by a web user or a search engine.
- It's conceptually cleaner: The main purpose of a web page is to provide information to the client, not to trigger an action on the server.

Of course, there are drawbacks as well:

- You have two Visual Studio projects instead of one.
- You might need to factor common code into a shared class library. (This can also be seen as an advantage.)
- Your system becomes more complex and, thus, potentially harder to maintain.

---

**Option 2**: If you need to stick to an aspx page, the easiest solution is probably to call the page via a command-line web client in a scheduled task. Since Windows does not provide any built-in command-line web clients, you'd have to download one such as `wget` or [`curl`](http://curl.haxx.se/). This related SO question contains the necessary command-line syntax:

- [Scheduled Tasks for ASP.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2927330/scheduled-tasks-for-asp-net/2927375#2927375)

Comment: Due to several reasons I am stuck with the .aspx page. But I guess I can still use Task Scheduler to run this page but how will it close the page afterwards ?

Comment: @StevieB: You could write a batch file that uses a command-line web client such as curl (http://curl.haxx.se/). It creates a connection to the web page, outputs the HTML code and then terminates.

Comment: @Heinzi, sorry mate thats a bit over my head. I thought this would be a simple task to schedule a .aspx to run every house, turns out its a nightmare

Comment: @StevieB: It's not as hard as it looks. Have a look at this related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2927330/scheduled-tasks-for-asp-net/2927375#2927375

Comment: @Heinze yeah its just every page I read people dicuss 15 different ways of doing it in very little detail, hard to find a working solution

Comment: For example in thread you linked they gave example wget -O - http://example.com/process.php 
So I tried run that command and I get 'wget' is not recognised as an internal or external command

Comment: @StevieB: I understand. The problem is, there *are* 15 different ways of doing that, and none of it is completely trivial. ;-) Another option would be to have the Windows Task Scheduler kill the IE window after opening your ASPx page (if you don't mind error messages in your Windows event logs): http://www.solo-technology.com/blog/2010/01/09/curl-to-the-rescue/

Comment: @StevieB: wget is an external program that you'd have to download, just like curl. There is no built-in command line web client in Windows.

Comment: I guess the error messages in Event Log is not a great way. curl can this be run via Windows Scheduled Task and it closes the browser afterwards ?

Comment: @StevieB: Yes. It does not open a browser window (it's a command-line application such as `dir`), so it does not need to be closed afterwards.

Comment: @Heinze, the CURL website gave me a 404 when trying to download the file so back to square one...I tried creating a scheduled task and putting the URL in and run the task but nothing happened is there any special settings need to be set for a scheduled task to run a .NET page ?

Comment: @StevieB: The following download link works fine for me: http://www.gknw.net/mirror/curl/win32/curl-7.21.6-ssl-sspi-zlib-static-bin-w32.zip

Answer (score 0):

use this sample to schedule a task in asp.net :

[enter link description here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/ASPNETService.aspx)

then you need to create `Hit.aspx` page witch will do what you want. then you should call that page every time (using `WebClient` class) the task execution time elapsed!

Answer (score 0):

You can use http://quartznet.sourceforge.net/ Quartz Job Scheduler.

With Quartz.net you can write a job which will request your web page with interval you choose.

or alternatively you can write an windows service which will request that web page.

Comment: Hey ok I downloaded this, but basically its just a visual studio solution folder I see. I can't see how I actually use this tool ? This is way to confusing for such a simple task

Comment: it seems very complicated, but learning such a tool can be good for further needs. thats way i pointed you that way. http://jvilalta.blogspot.com/2009/03/getting-started-with-quartznet-part-1.html here is a series of blog post about quartz.net.